# Why puts() not working

Tags: c

I am a beginner and I started with this basic program which is below.
I don't know when I run it , it asks me " Enter the card_name" as expected , however it does not put the answer like "Card has gone up or down".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char card_name[3];
    puts(" Enter the card_name: ");
    scanf("2s%", card_name);
    int val = 0;
    if (card_name[0] == 'K') {
        val = 10;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'Q') {
        val =10 ;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'J') {
        val =10 ;
    } else if (card_name[0] == 'A') {
        val =11 ;
    } else {
        val = atoi(card_name);
    }

    /*Check if the value is 3 to 6 */
    if ((val > 2) && (val <7))
        puts(" COunt has gone up");
    /* Other wise check if the card was , J , Q or K */
    else if (val == 10)
        puts(" Count has gone down");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't `puts` that is broken in this code. what exactly is `2s%` supposed to be doing for a [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format ? Pretty sure you meant `%2s`. *Checking* the result of `scanf` rather than ignoring it would probably have showed you what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks a lot ...I am so bad even copying. But Kudos to you.

Comment: @Beeran Always blame yourself - never compiler or standard librarties. I saw many funny folks here - saying: `my program does not work properly - I have found the compiler error - then long assembly listing.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `%2s` instead of `2s%` for the `scanf()` statement.

Comment: Downvoting - your answer is just the copy of the @WhozCraig comment. Dont build your "reputation" on someones knowledge. Shame

Comment: Not a copy, even tough i dont have thousands of reputation i can tel what is wrong. Plus it is his fault not putting answer in answers section since when somebody googles this problem they wont find a verified answer but a comment

Comment: be serious. Comments index same good as answers. If I was you I would delete it. But it is about the honour, not very valuable nowadays.

Comment: Well i still gained reputation so i wont delete it, and please don't question my honor on this site, if you ever meet me in person you can say whatever you want :)

Comment: It was general but `if the cap fits .....`

Comment: No we are not fighting(even tough it may seem like this) just having a conversation with different opinions : )

Comment: Downvoting here is incorrect. The answer is correct and WhozCraig chose not to put it as an answer. An actual answer allows the OP to mark the question as solved, so everybody is winning here.

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks Sir , yes I will always keep this approach of what I did wrong.